# Internet Explorer distorts SVG image upon matrix transformation

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I have an SVG path which is being filled by an image, however, when I put the SVG object through a number of transformations, while the image appears fine on Chrome and Firefox, on Internet Explorer (and Edge), the image becomes all distorted/pixelated.

This is a problem because I am trying to put this into a .NET "WebBrowser" control, which uses IE as the base (but that's beside the point)

Take this code:

```
<html><body>
 <h1>Rotation Test</h1>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 550 400" width="550" height="400"> 
   <g><defs>
      <pattern  patternTransform="matrix(0 -0.252762 1 0 -336.5 62.95)" id="f1330" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 62 131" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  width="62" height="131" tp="7"><image width="62" height="131" href="bitofballoon.png" /></pattern>
   </defs></g>
   <g id="A04133" type="shape"><g ><path transform="matrix(0.200745 0.54213 -2.44809 0.906509 379.75 72.25)" fill="url(#f1330)" d="M -336.5 62.95 L -336.5 -62.9 L 336.5 -62.9 L 336.5 62.95 L -336.5 62.95" /></g></g>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

(I tried putting in as a jsfiddle but it seems IE is not supported)

This this code is autogenerated by a tool designed to convert Flash to HTML 5, so I'm hoping that major changes are not required. (I simplified for the sake of posting here)

Anyway if you open that in Chrome or Firefox you see this...

[image]

(I'm not too worried about the clipping...)

But if you open in IE it looks like this

[image]

As you can see the image appears to be a very low resolution image that has been expanded, as opposed to the Chrome version.

Why is this happening, and more importantly, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Observation: you have a stray closing `defs` inside the group `<g id="0:4:133" `. Also the id is begining with a digit

Comment: @enxaneta - OK - I've updated the code with respect to your observations but the problem remains...

Comment: I try to check the document for [patternTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternTransform) and we can see that compatibility is unknown for the IE browser. This can be the reason for the issue. Further, I also suggest you to try to check the issue by removing the height and width from the SVG. Here is a [helpful blog](https://ctidd.com/2015/svg-background-scaling) that may give you some information.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - Thanks, that was helpful to know. I ended up modifying the image to be closer to its starting orientation, then in the `patternTransform`, used `translate` and `scale` instead of a `matrix` to get it as close as possible to how I wanted it to look, and left the `<path transform...` as it is to get it into the orientation I wanted. This seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @colmde, from your last comment it looks like you have solved the issue. Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 1):

So here is my resolution. There are two transformations as you can see in the code, both using `matrix`. I believe the combination of both is what IE was struggling with.

So my solution was to take one out. Effectively, what the `patternTransform` is doing is rotating it 90 degrees anti-clockwise and doing some stretching and squashing. So I used photoshop to turn the image sideways, and changed the `patternTransform` matrix to scale / rotate.

```
<html><body>
<h1>Rotation Test</h1>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 550 400" width="550" height="400"> 
   <g><defs>
      <pattern id="f1330" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 62 131" patternTransform="scale(1, 0.253), translate(336.5, 249)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="131" height="62" tp="7"><image width="131" height="62" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href="sideballoon.png" /></pattern>
   </defs></g>
   <g id="A04133" type="shape"><g ><path transform="matrix(0.200745 0.54213 -2.44809 0.906509 379.75 72.25)" fill="url(#f1330)" d="M -336.5 62.95 L -336.5 -62.9 L 336.5 -62.9 L 336.5 62.95 L -336.5 62.95 " /></g></g>
</svg>
</body></html>
```

Had to translate the image too as it had become displaced